# display selected value from database in select box in vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Issue -- contact id is not displaying the selected value which is fetched from the database .

This is my select box code -

```
<form @submit.prevent="updateProject" method="put" autocomplete="off">
 <select id="select" v-model="form.project.contact_id" class="form-select" required>
  <option v-for="contact in contacts" :key="contact.id" :selected="contact.id == 14">{{ 
   contact.name }}</option>
 </select> 

 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Project Name" v- 
 model="form.project.project_name">
</form>
```

and below is my script file

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        projectId: this.$route.params.id,
        contacts: [],
        showSelectedInjection: false,
        form: {
        project: {},
        contact: [], 
        },
      }
    },
    mounted: function () {
      this.getProjectDetails();
      this.initialData();
    },
    methods: {
      initialData() {
        this.$axios.$get("/api/projects/initial-data") 
        .then(function (response) {
          this.contacts = response;
          //console.log(this.contacts);
        }.bind(this));
      }, 
      getProjectDetails() {
        this.$axios.$get('/api/projects/' + this.projectId + '/edit')
        .then(response => {
          this.form.project = response;     
          console.log(this.form.project);     
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.$toast.error("Error fetching contact details");
        });
      }, 
      updateProject() 
      {
        this.$axios.$put('/api/projects/' + this.projectId , this.form)
        .then(response => {
          this.$toast.success("Project Updated Successfully");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.$toast.error("Error updating sale");
        });
      }
    }
    }
</script>
```

Project Table is storing Contact id, Project Name, Budget, Start Date, End Date.
so whenever i am fetching the data of project with the help of console.log(this.form.project), it shows

```
{"id":1,"project_name":"website","budget":"10000","start_date_time":"2022-06-08","end_date_time":"2022-06-14","location":"jdfj","contact_id":1,"contract_id":null,"created_at":"2022-06-14T20:29:53.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-06-14T20:29:53.000000Z"}
```

I want to display this contact id as selected id in my select box, Please help

Comment: let v-model handle the selection. remove selected attribute from the option and add value attribute `<option v-for="contact in contacts" :key="contact.id" value="contact.id">{{ contact.name }}</option>`

Comment: I have tried this but its not working !!

Answer (score 0):

initialize the form object in project parameter.

```
  data() {
  return {
    projectId: this.$route.params.id,
    contacts: [],
    showSelectedInjection: false,
    form: {
    project: new Form(),
    contact: [], 
    },
  }
},
```

Comment: If i do this, It doesnt display page and shows - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'project')